# Прототипное наследование в javascript

Tags: javascript, наследование, prototype

Есть такой код. Первый объект назначаем прототипом второго.

```
var objectParent = {
  name: 'Baga'
};

var objectInherit = {};
objectInherit.prototype = objectParent;

console.log(objectInherit.name); //undefined ?!!
```

Почему нельзя достучаться из второго объекта до свойств первого напрямую без функций?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит ознакомится в чём разница `prototype` и `__proto__`, например, [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140810/).

```js
var objectParent = {
  name: 'Baga'
};

var objectInherit = Object.create(objectParent);

console.log(objectInherit.name); // Baga
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы создаете просто свойство prototype у вашего нового объекта, и ни каким наследованием тут не пахнет.
Для проверки, можете посмотреть

```
objectInherit.prototype.name // baga
```

Но автоматически при вызове просто objectInherit.name такого перехода не будет.